# How do I capture a large(r) set of synonyms and antonyms with Python's NLTK WordNet?

Tags: python, nltk, wordnet

I have a word (for instance 'fight'), and I'd like to find a list of all antonyms and synonyms.

I'm using this thesaurus entry for comparison.

http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/fight

Currently I have the following code,

```
from nltk import wordnet as wn
from itertools import chain

def flatten(l):
    return list( chain ( *l ) )

def get_variants(word):
    synonyms = []
    for syn in wn.synsets(word):
        synonyms.append( [syn.lemmas] )
        synonyms.append([ s.lemmas for s in syn.similar_tos() ] )
        synonyms.append([ s.lemmas for s in syn.hypernyms() ] )
        synonyms.append([ s.lemmas for s in syn.hyponyms() ] )

    return set( flatten( flatten( synonyms ) ) )

def get_synonyms(word):
    return sorted( [v.name for v in get_variants(word)] )

def get_antonyms(word):
    antonyms = flatten( [v.antonyms() for v in get_variants(word)] )
    return sorted( [a.name for a in antonyms] )

fight_synonyms = """action altercation argument battle bout brawl clash combat conflict confrontation
contest controversy disagreement dispute duel exchange feud match melee quarrel riot rivalry round
scuffle skirmish struggle war wrangling affray broil brush contention difficulty dissension dogfight
engagement fisticuffs fracas fray free-for-all fuss hostility joust row ruckus rumble scrap scrimmage
set-to strife tiff to-do tussle battle royal sparring match""".split()

print sorted(list(set(fight_synonyms) - set(get_synonyms('fight'))))

fight_antonyms = """accord agreement calm concord harmony peace quiet truce
friendliness friendship kindness""".split()

print sorted( list( set( fight_antonyms ) - set( get_antonyms('fight') ) ) )
```

With the missed synonym result of

```
['altercation', 'bout', 'broil', 'confrontation', 'contest', 'difficulty',
'disagreement', 'dispute', 'dissension', 'exchange', 'fracas', 'fuss',
'hostility', 'match', 'melee', 'quarrel', 'riot', 'rivalry', 'round',
'row', 'royal', 'ruckus', 'scrimmage', 'sparring', 'strife', 'tiff',
'to-do', 'wrangling']
```

and missed antonym result of

```
['accord', 'agreement', 'calm', 'concord', 'friendliness', 'friendship', 'harmony', 'kindness', 'peace', 'quiet', 'truce']
```

As can be seen, I'm missing a number of important synonyms and antonyms for fight.

Any suggestions for how I can reasonably broaden the results - are there some other ways to find variants via WordNet I'm missing?

Comment: You could try to start with a larger set of synonyms, taken from various different thesauri and you could try to include synonyms of synonyms, although you'll add quite a bit of junk to your results this way.